# Visual Studio for Windows Phone - Run option is not showing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, direct3d

I created a windows phone project and was running it fine from the original place I stored it. 
I copied ALL files to my skydrive, and now today am picking up from where I left off on another computer.

When I open the project in visual studio, the run button is no longer clickable.

Anyone know what I need to do to make the run/in emulator/device button come back up?

Comment: Have you verified that this new computer have `WindowsPhone8 SDK` and `Emulator` services installed and running?

Comment: Yes, it seems the windows phone visual studio 2012 kit is the SDK, although i'm repairing it to make sure there's no weird problems. Do I have to denote the fact the c++ project needs to be run from a certain file or something?

Comment: Okay, I have repaired the installation and it's all working now lol